# Print from windows to lots of different printers

Tags: samba, cups

My company has lots of different (network) printers. I want to simplify printing.
My plan is following:
*Install a linux (BSD) based CUPS/Samba server (It will handle drivers)
*Print from windows using a simple uniform driver (Microsoft PS class driver ?)

Has anybody some good instructions to do that?

Comment: The CUPS testpage looks good, but if I print from Windows using Microsoft PS class driver the image appears with some milimeter (1/4 inch) right